# How to get the count of test classes failed in the allure report instead of @Test methods failed count

Tags: java, testing, junit4, allure

I'm running a Junit test suite with multiple test classes, each test class having multiple @Test methods. Is there any way or possibility for allure to report it as only 1 failure per class irrespective of how many @Test methods fail in that.

Currently, if there are 2 @Test methods fail in one class and 1 @Test method fail in another class, allure is reporting the failed test cases count as 3. In the overview tab, I want failed test cases count as 2 instead of 3.

Thanks in advance.
Jairam